# Could This Python Program Be Simplified Or Better Written?

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

Okay so I have been learning quite a bit of Python over the past few days, two or three, and I decided to take my knowledge and create something simple, but sort of entertaining, so I created a Guessing Game.

After about 30 minutes of creating this program and getting it to work 100% I was wondering if there was anything I could have done better, etc.  I want to make sure I learn from any mistakes so I appreciate it!

So here is the code:

```
import random

def guessingGame():

    randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 10)
    yourGuess = int(input("Take A Guess, Numbers 1 Through 10: "))

    while yourGuess != randomNumber:
        print("DOH! You Did Not Guess Right, TRY AGAIN")
        yourGuess = int(input("Take A Guess, Numbers 1 Through 10: "))
    else:
        if yourGuess == randomNumber:
            print("Congrats You Beat The Guess Game!")

playGame = input("Would You Like To Play The Guessing Game (Y/N): ")

if playGame == "Y" or playGame == "y":
    print("Okay Lets Play!")
    guessingGame()

elif playGame == "N" or playGame == "n":
    print("Okay Thanks Anyways!")
    break
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: This question probably belongs on CodeReview

Comment: `randrange(1, 10)` will give you the numbers `0-9`. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) here. You want to do either `randrange(1, 11)`, or the more obvious `randint(1, 10)`

Comment: `break` outside a loop is a syntax error

Comment: Thanks for the suggetions, etc.  I didn't mean to add the break it is actually not in the program itself, but yeah.

Also I totally forgot about the randrange(1, 11) over 1, 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't need to recheck the condition in the `else` - you already know it's ==

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
if playGame == "Y" or playGame == "y":
    print("Okay Lets Play!")
    guessingGame()
```

I kind of like

```
if playGame.lower() == "y":
    # ...
```

I even better like:

```
def quit():
    print("Okay Thanks Anyways!")


actions = {"y": guessingGame}
actions.get(playGame.lower(), quit)()
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things I noticed:

- You should handle the case where user tries to guess something that doesn't look like a number, say the letter 'a' for example.
- Python style guide says to prefer lower_with_underscores over CamelCase for variable names.
- The line `yourGuess = int(input("Take A Guess, Numbers 1 Through 10: "))` is unnecessarily duplicated, see below for one possible way to refactor that part.

General cleanup:

```
import random

def guessing_game():
  random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
  assert random_number in range(1, 11)
  your_guess = None
  while your_guess != random_number:
    try:
      your_guess = int(input("Take A Guess, Numbers 1 Through 10: "))
    except ValueError:
      print("That wasn't a number")
      continue

    if your_guess != random_number:
      print("DOH! You Did Not Guess Right, TRY AGAIN")
    else:
      print("Congrats You Beat The Guess Game!")
      break

play_game = None
while play_game not in ['y', 'n']:
  play_game = input("Would You Like To Play The Guessing Game (Y/N): ").lower()

if play_game == "y":
  print("Okay Lets Play!")
  guessing_game()
else:
  assert play_game == "n":
  print("Okay Thanks Anyways!")
```

Comment: One disadvantage here is that if you put in a non-number, it'll still do the `your_guess != random_number` check and print out the error message from the last loop around / default `None` value. Might be better to change the (unnecessary) `pass` into a `continue` or put the rest of the loop into an `else` from the `try` statement.

Comment: yeah, good catch .. i actually was meaning continue and wrote a useless pass statement instead for some reason

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import randint

def getInt(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("That's no integer!")

def play():
    secret = randint(1,10)
    while True:
        guess = getInt("Take a guess (1-10):")
        if guess==secret:
            print("Congrats, you beat The Guess Game!")
            break
        else:
            print("D'oh! You guessed wrong. Try again!")

def main():
    while True:
        inp = input("Would you like to play The Guessing Game? (Y/N)").lower()
        if inp=="y":
            print("Okay, let's play!")
            play()
        elif inp=="n":
            print("Alright. Thanks anyways!")
            break
        else:
            print("You don't follow directions too good, eh?")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could use a "break" statement inside a while loop, as in

```
import random

def guessingGame():    
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 10)

    while True:

        yourGuess = input("Take A Guess, Numbers 1 Through 10: ")

        if !yourGuess.isdigit():
            print ("That's not a number!")
        elif int(yourGuess) not in range(1,10):
            print("I said between 1 and 10!")
        elif int(yourGuess) != randomNumber:
            print("DOH! You Did Not Guess Right, TRY AGAIN")
        else:
            break

    print("Congrats You Beat The Guess Game!")

playGame = input("Would You Like To Play The Guessing Game (Y/N): ")

if playGame.lower() == "y":
    print("Okay Lets Play!")
    guessingGame()

elif playGame.lower() == "n":
    print("Okay Thanks Anyways!")
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) documentation on naming conventions and Python's style of coding.

```
import random

def guessing_game(x=1, y=10):
    """
    A simple number guessing game.
    """
    while int(input("Take A Guess, Numbers 1 Through 10: ")) \
                                          != random.randrange(x, y):
        print("DOH! You Did Not Guess Right, TRY AGAIN")

    print("Congrats You Beat The Guess Game!")

    if input("Would You Like To Play The Guessing Game (Y/N): ") == 'Y':
        print("Okay Lets Play!")
        guessing_game()
    else:
        print("Okay Thanks Anyways!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    guessing_game(1, 10)
```